# Running two arrays in a for each loop

Tags: php

am trying to get the results from `$num` and `$name` simultaneously. That is where:

```
num[0] = name[0]
```

it seems to start running but uses the first value gotten from $num for all the values of `$name`.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$num = $_POST['num'];
foreach ($num as $num){       
  foreach ($name as $name){ 
    $num * $name
  }
}       
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have  foreach  ($num as $num) and ($name as $name)  try using differnet var name for the assignememt in foreach

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    foreach ($num as $val1){ 
      foreach ($name as $val2){ 
        $val1* $val2;
      }
    }  

  .......
```